# How To refresh a Tkinter Frame Every time user Navigate to some frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter Application that involves many Frames/Pages and I Want to update/refresh the page on which I am going every time I Use `show_frame` or navigate to that page. Because what i need is that the frame i am going to be taken has some Data that will come from previous page or the page from which i am coming from and will be used in the frame which i am going and tkinter Creates frames at start and there widgets remain as it is until i do not refresh those frames or i change something
my code

```
import tkinter as tk
import connectionPage
import startPage
import loginPage
import signupPage
import dashboardPage


class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}
        self.attributes('-fullscreen', True)

        for F in (startPage.StartPage, connectionPage.connect_page, loginPage.login_page, signupPage.signup_page, dashboardPage.dashboard_page):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(startPage.StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        self.update()
        frame.tkraise()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = tkinterApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

When I click on buttons to navigate to some pages to change frame `show_frame` function is called I have added `self.update()` but it is not working.

THIS is Shortest Frame

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import IntVar, ttk, CENTER, StringVar
import tkinter as tk
import connectionPage
LARGEFONT = ("Verdana", 35)

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = ttk.Label(self, text="HI", font=LARGEFONT)
        label.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

        controller.after(3000, lambda: controller.show_frame(connectionPage.connect_page))
```

Comment: Calling `self.update()` is useless for your case.  You need to update the widgets in a frame using `.config(...)` or update some tkinter variables which are associated with widgets using `.set(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Please if you can show How?

Comment: It really depends on how you create those frames.  Better provide [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 i have added a frame example

Comment: Your example is not a [mre].  Also there is nothing changed when you switch from `StartPage` to `connect_page`.

Comment: @acw1668 I want to refresh/reload The Frame on which I am going Every Time I change frame using ```controller.show_frame```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239220/discussion-between-lexi-and-acw1668).